# How to morph an object at runtime while keeping past information?

Tags: oop, state-machine

Is it possible to morph an object at runtime depending on its current state and keep all past information?

Say I have the following (in pseudo-code):

```
class Vehicle {
  int state, lat, long;
  void run();
}

class Plane : Vehicle {
  void run() {fly();}
}

class Car : Vehicle {
  void run() {drive();}
}

class Boat : Vehicle {
  void run() {navigate();}
}

void main() {
  // Setup code goes here
  Vehicle vehicle = new Vehicle();
  while(true) {
    switch(vehicle->state){
      case(1): vehicle = new Plane();
      case(2): vehicle = new Car();
      case(3): vehicle = new Boat();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible in the sense you've wrote it, but it is possible to design system with behavior you want:

1. You have one object, it is the same object during runtime
2. Object has different behaviors
3. Current behavior is based on current state

*Its small, but very important difference with what you wrote in question, in this approach we're not morphing object, but it's behavior only*

There are could be multiple different implementations, depending on full set of requirements, here is simplest one, assuming that behavior changes position only:

```
class Position {
    int lat, long;
}

interface PositionCalculator {
    Position calc(Position old);
}

class Vehicle {
    private Position pos;
    void modify(PositionCalculator calc) {pos = calc.calc(pos);}
}

class CarCalculator : PositionCalculator {
    Position calc(Position old) {return navigate(old);}
}
class PlaneCalculator : PositionCalculator {
    Position calc(Position old) {return fly(old);}
}

void main() {
    Vehicle vehicle = new Vehicle();
    PositionCalculator plane = new PlaneCalculator()
    PositionCalculator car = new CarCalculator();

    while(true) {
        if (vehicle is in air)
            vehicle.modify(plane);
        else if (vehicle is on road)
            vehicle.modify(car);
    }
}
```